# Issue Freeing 2D Dynamic Memory

Tags: c, malloc, free

I'm unsure what the problem running this is. I know that if I remove the second for loop (where it is supposed to free the inner array), it runs fine.

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char *board = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 8);
    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
        board[i] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 8);

    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
        free(board[i]);
    free(board);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Changed tag to C as this is straight C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `board` is a pointer to `char`, i.e. much like a string. That means each "element" in `board` is a *single character* and not a pointer.

That means when you in the loop do

```
board[i] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 8);
```

you will assign a pointer to a `char`, and not a `char *`.

You want to make `board` a pointer to *pointers* to `char`:

```
char **board = malloc(...)
```

Oh and by the way, you are allocating more than 8 characters for each string in the loop. You are allocating memory for 8 *pointers*. You should do e.g.

```
board[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
```

Or, since `sizeof(char)` is always equal to `1`

```
board[i] = malloc(8);
```

---

Furthermore, and I don't know if this applies to you, but remember that strings in C have a special terminator character at the end. So if you want a string of eight characters you need to make space for *nine* characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `board` is a pointer-to-char, but your inner loop is allocating memory for eight pointers-to-char, rather than eight chars.

Assuming that your `board` variable type is what you really intended to have, then your code for the inner loop needs to read as follows:

```
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
        board[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
```

Comment: Even better - `board[i]  = malloc( sizeof *board[i] * 8);`